# Accessing controller variables and functions - ngDialog

Tags: angularjs, ng-dialog

I've created an `ngDialog` but I can't seem to access `variables` and `functions` in my `controller` within it.

This is my code;

```
ngDialog.open({
    template: 'mod-details',
    className: "ngDialog-theme-large",
    showClose: false,
    closeByDocument: false,
    closeByEscape: false,
    data: {
        orderItem: item
    }
});
```

Any functions attached to elements within the `ngDialog` that are in my `controller` don't get called. Same for variables as well.

I have a `ng-repeat` that repeats `checkboxes` inside the `ngDialog`

```
<div class="group-items" ng-if="modifier.max_selection_points > 1 || (modifier.max_selection_points == 1 && modifier.min_selection_points == 0)">
    <div ng-repeat="item in modifier.menu_modifier_items" class="modifier-item multiple">
        <label for="<%modifier.id + '_' + item.id%>">
            <input id="<%modifier.id + '_' + item.id%>"
                   class="checkbox-branded"
                   type="checkbox"
                   name="<%item.name%>"
                   ng-model="item.selected"
                   ng-class="{'not-available': !item.available}"
                   title="<%item.name%>"
                   value="<%item.id%>">
    <span class="item-name">
        <span ng-bind="item.name"></span>
        <span ng-bind="priceDelta(modifier, item)"></span>
    </span>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any function I assign to `ng-click` of the `checkbox` doesn't get called. Also checking `variables` and then deciding whether `ng-disabled` is true also doesn't work.

It has no visibility of functions, variables in my controller

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just need to pass your scope to it. add

```
scope: $scope
```

to your ngDialog.open options.

Comment: I still can't see my functions even adding `$scope`